# Does parallel_for_each (tbb) process each element of array in a different thread?

Tags: arrays, tbb

From the [documentation of oneapi](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/1.1-rev-1/elements/oneTBB/source/algorithms/functions/parallel_for_each_func.html):

> The sequence form parallel_for_each(first, last, body) applies a function object body over a sequence [first,last). Items may be processed in parallel.

What does this mean exactly? I'm studying TBB for one of my classes and it says that the iteration is done serially. Is this basically, for example, I have an array

```
int* myarray = a really big array
```

and for each element in my array I want to do

```
myarray[i] = some function that takes a really long time to execute
```

and I have 4 CPU cores that are available.

will `parallel_for_each` basically take 4 threads and each thread will process one element? like

```
array[0] = result from thread 1
array[1] = result from thread 2
array[2] = result from thread 3
array[3] = result from thread 4
```

and so on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parallel_for_each` processes work items in parallel.It creates a thread for each single element of your array.
Refer to below link for more details:
https://oneapi-src.github.io/oneTBB/main/tbb_userguide/Cook_Until_Done_parallel_do.html

Use `parallel_for_each` when each objects work is relatively large and number of objects is few and each object has un-equal work.